# $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}} {x^{t-1}}\,dx}, \quad 1< t<2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

let $1<t<2$.
I need to evaluate

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$$

If $t>2$ one can easily apply the dominated convergence theorem 
because
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty1}\,e^{-\epsilon x}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx+
\int_{1}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx\\
\leq \int_{0}^{1}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx+
\int_{1}^{\infty}\,\,\frac{1}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx\\
\leq \int_{0}^{1}\,x\,dx+
\int_{1}^{\infty}\,\,\frac{1}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx<\infty.
$$

Now, if we change variables $\epsilon x\rightarrow x$ we get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x} \,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx=\epsilon^{t-2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-x}\,\frac{|\sin{\frac{x}{\epsilon}}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx $$ and $\lim \epsilon^{t-2}=\infty$ when $t<2$.

Does $\lim \int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-x}\,\frac{|\sin{\frac{x}{\epsilon}}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$ exist ?

At least, can we show that 
$\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-x}\,\frac{|\sin{\frac{x}{\epsilon}}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$ is bounded uniformly in $\epsilon$ when $1<t< 2$?

Thanks

Comment: Another approach could be using the monotone convergence theorem that implies $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$. The latter integral diverges for $1\leq t<2$.

Comment: So why not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the monotone convergence theorem 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\,e^{-\epsilon x} \,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\,\frac{|\sin{x}|^{t}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$$ which is a divergent integral because

$$|\sin{x}|^{t}\geq \sin^{2}{x}$$ for all $\;1\leq t\leq 2\;$ 
and
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\,\frac{\sin^{2}{x}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\,\frac{1-\cos{2x}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx.$$

Finally, the integral 
$\int_{1}^{\infty}\,\frac{1}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$ diverges while 
the integral 
$\int_{1}^{\infty}\,\frac{\cos{2x}}
{x^{t-1}}\,dx$ converges by the Dirichlet test.